# Python: coursera assignments - Dictionary chapter

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to solve the assignments from coursera - Python.

Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out who has the sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file. After the dictionary is produced, the program reads through the dictionary using a maximum loop to find the most prolific committer.

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

lst = list()
for line in handle:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("From"):
        words = line.split()
        email = words[1]
        lst.append(email)

dct = dict()
for email in lst:
    dct[email] = dct.get(email,0)+1

bigcount = None
email_address = None
for key,value in dct.items():
    if bigcount is None or value > bigcount:
        bigcount = value
        email_address = key

print email_address, bigcount
```

My code runs, but the desired output should be: cwen@iupui.edu 5  , but i get somehow "doubled" output: cwen@iupui.edu 10

Did anyone solved this problem? Could you please give me a hint what have i missed? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you print the output of the other emails in the dict and be sure this is not unique to that email?

Comment: Everything looks ok, you could try to print lines that enters the if to see the problem, and show your example file.

Comment: `for email in lst:` duplicated , maybe you got two or more line same text. Get unique values on your input text before handling on a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check line 3726 and 3763. There is a colon after **From**. I think you are missing that while searching manually.

> Line 3726 From cwen@iupui.edu Thu Jan  3 16:23:48 2008
>
> Line 3763 From: cwen@iupui.edu

Otherwise the code is correct. It is showing correct output.

Comment: Hi! Thank a lot to all fot the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
 name = input("Enter file:")
 if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
 handle = open(name)
 word=list()
 for line in handle:
     if line.startswith('From'):
        words=line.split()
        word.append(words)

count=dict()
for word in words:
count[word]=count.get(word,0)+1

bigcount = None
bigword= None
for count,word in count.items():
    if count > bigcount:
    bigcount=count
    bigword=word

print(bigcount,bigword)
```

Comment: am getting the output as cwen@iupui.edu 1,instead of cwen@iupui.edu 5....

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for this assignment is 5, not 10.  As qmaruf pointed out, there are lines with and without colons.  The assignment states to find all lines starting with "From ".  You are finding all lines that start with "From".  Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
counts = dict()
handle = open(fname)
for line in handle:
   line=line.rstrip()
   if line.startswith('From '):
       words=line.split()
       counts[words[1]]=counts.get(words[1],0)+1
bigcount=0
for word,count in counts.items():
   if bigcount == 0 or count>bigcount:
       bigword=word
       bigcount=count

print(bigword,bigcount)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at SO help section on [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), specifically the part about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You should first and foremost help the question poster solve their immediate issue, ideally with an explanation what's happening and why are you suggesting the particular solution. Then you can add suggestions for other improvements, but also accompany them with reasoning them - why you believe it is (or isn't) the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = input('enter the file name')
fh = open(fname)
counts = dict()
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('From'):
        words = line.split()
        for word in words :
            counts[words[1]]= counts.get(words[1],0)+1

bigcount=0
for word,count in counts.items():
   if bigcount == 0 or count>bigcount:
       bigword=word
       bigcount=count

print(bigword,bigcount)
```

This is very simple and easy to understand so use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code snippet:

```py
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
counts=dict()
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        line=line.split()
        counts[line[1]]=counts.get(line[1],0)+1
bigword=None
bigcount=0
for key,val in counts.items():
  if bigcount==0 or val>bigcount : 
        bigcount=val
        bigword=key
print(bigword,bigcount)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
counts = dict()
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
fhand = open(name)
for line in fhand:
       line = line.rstrip()
       if not line.startswith('From ') : continue
       words = line.split()            
       counts[words[1]]=counts.get(words[1],0)+1 
st = 0 
for k in counts:
       if counts[k] > st :
       st = counts[k]
       addy = k
print (addy, st)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word=list()
count=dict()
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith("From ") :
        continue
    words=line.split()
    word.append(words[1])#gets the emails from list
for name in word:
    count[name]=count.get(name,0)+1
bigemail=bigcount=None
for word,count in count.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigcount=count
        bigemail=word
print(bigemail,bigcount)
```

Comment: Please add a sentence explaining your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just take a closer look at Exercise.
They have said that you should take all strings that are starting from **"From "**, not **"From"**.

Answer (score 0):

```
counts=dict()
txt=open("mbox-short.txt")
for line in txt :
    if line.startswith("From "):
        x=line.split()
        b=x[1]
        counts[b]=counts.get(b,0)+1
#print(counts)
big_word=0
big_count=0
for word,count in counts.items():
    if big_count<count :
        big_count=count
        big_word=word
print(big_word,big_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake in this assignment is to miss the whitespace between the *m* of From and the closing quotation mark. In other words, it should be "From " instead of "From"

```
if line.startswith(**"From"**):
```

Your code is counting extra lines because of the missing whitespace.

Here's my version of the code:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

email = []

d = dict() 

for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith("From "): continue
    line = line.strip().split()
    email += [line[1]]
    
for e in email:
    d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + 1

max_email = max(d, key=d.get)

print(max_email, d[max_email])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code, I have tried to make it detailed and easy to understand:

```
# create the histogram
counts = dict()
file_name = input('Enter file name: ')
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
    for line in file_handle:
        words = line.rstrip().split()

        if len(words) == 0:
            continue

        if words[0] == 'From':
            email = words[1]
            counts[email] = counts.get(email, 0) + 1

    print(counts)

# ----------------------------------------

# loop through the histogram to get the max values
    max_email = None
    max_count = None
    for email, count in counts.items():
        if max_count is None or count > max_count :
            max_count = count
            max_email = email
    print(max_email, max_count)

except:
    print('Invalid Input')
```